# WPF How to raise an Individual property change from DataGrid bounded to a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

As the question ask, how is this done ?

From a DataGrid I can get the SelectedRow of that collection  that has been bounded to its ItemSource, but I really need a setter and getter for an individual property that belongs inside the ObservableCollection.

For example, I need to catch when a user checks a bool property inside a datagrid, so then the setter would be set to "false/true". So something like

```
    //But the Archive property is in the DataContext of the row item... 
    //so this wouldnt work, I think..

    private bool m_Archived = false;

    public bool Archived
    {
        get { return m_Archived; }
        set
        {
            m_Archived = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Archived");
        }
    }
```

But remember this property is part of the ObservableCollection (DataContext)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register to each collection item property changed, then to control when the desired property has changed, then change the archived property. Check this sample code:

```
private ObservableCollection<TClass> _SomeObservableCollection;

public ObservableCollection<TClass> SomeObservableCollection
{
    get { return _SomeObservableCollection ?? (_SomeObservableCollection = SomeObservableCollectionItems()); }
}

private ObservableCollection<TClass> SomeObservableCollectionItems()
{
    var resultCollection = new ObservableCollection<TClass>();

    foreach (var item in SomeModelCollection)
    {
        var newPoint = new TClass(item) {IsLocated = true};
        newPoint.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
        resultCollection.Add(newPoint);
    }

    resultCollection.CollectionChanged += OnSomeObservableCollectionCollectionChanged;

    return resultCollection;
}

private void OnSomeObservableCollectionCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (TClass TClass in e.NewItems)
        {
            TClass.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (TClass TClass in e.OldItems)
        {
            TClass.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
    if (!Patient.HasChanges)
        Patient.HasChanges = true;
}


private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName != "ItemArchivedProperty") return;
    // set Archived = true or set Archived = false 
}
```

This is just an example, but it should works. Hope it helps.